# Full calendar refresh events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used this full calendar which takes events from ajax call
i want it to get new ajax values on button click event, how could this work?

```
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '2014-09-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events:{
    url: 'emp-attendance-ajax.php?id=' + id
},




        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's resolved i used this

```
events: {
                url: 'emp-attendance-ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: function() { // a function that returns an object
                    return {
                        id: id
                    };
                }
            },
```

instead of this one

```
events:{
 url: 'employees-attendance/emp-attendance-ajax.php?id=' + i++ 
},
```

and it's worked

Answer (score 0):

if you need to update one event ( better because faster ) : 
`.fullCalendar( 'updateEvent' , event )`
else I think it's 
`.fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' )`

Comment: I'll be at work today si won't answer fast but what is your error message?

Comment: And I said .fullCalendar but you need your jQuery selector before ( for you $('#calendar').fullCalendar )

Comment: when i used .fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' ), thats worked but "i" still equal to 1 as var i = 1 at begining

events: {
url: 'employees-attendance/emp-attendance-ajax.php?id=' + i++
},

Comment: Thanks alot it's resolved like i described below
@Thomas